# C# Prevent the Console window from displaying for half a second?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a super basic consol application why does the consol display for less then half a second and then exit?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyHelloWorldApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing nothing after the `Console.Writeline()` method so the app will close.

Adding a `Console.ReadKey()` will stop the app from closing until you have pressed a key.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using VisualStudio try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or just <kbd>F5</kbd> key. One of them will do the trick.

<kbd>F5</kbd> - Will let you to run the application with debugging enabled.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> - Will run application with out debugging.

Or Try:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

At the end of Main method which will let program run until <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.

Comment: Downvoted for poor information. Please read the post. F5 or Ctrl F5 will start the application, with or without debugging. It will not stop the behaviour above from happening. Also adding another WriteLine() will not stop the application from exiting, you need something to halt execution of the Console before continuing or exiting and this should be performed with ReadKey() or similiar.

Comment: Running the app from the command line should keep the output open.

Comment: Running the app using F5 will _not_ keep the window open, nor will adding another WriteLine(). I have to admit that running without debugging (CTRL + F5) will keep the window open, so apologies.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you're debugging, in which case it disappears because execution of your program has finished.

Add a `Console.ReadLine();` call to the end of your main method and it won't exit until you hit the return key.

Answer (score 1):

it starts, runs, writes "Test" then closes.
add

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

after your `WriteLine("Test")` and it'll wait for you to press ENTER before closing.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Threading;

Thread.Sleep(500);//500 msec.
```

Comment: +1 for not wasting any more time than the 1/2 second he asked for.